# CMD - composer and artisan commands stopped working

Tags: laravel, cmd, composer-php, laravel-artisan

After a break, I decided to work on one of my Laravel projects again. The "php artisan serve" command worked fine before, and so it did on other projects. But now it doesn't work on any project and I have no clue why. The composer commands don't work either. I tested ipconfig and this does work, so I guess it has something to do with commands from 3rd parties?

Things I tried:

- Run CMD in administrator mode
- Check if the environment paths were still correct (and they seem so)

I got a big Windows update a few days ago and I think it has something to do with it, but I can't find anyone with similar issues.

The command below just gives me a blank line, and then a new line with the path and option to type a command.

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\webshop>php artisan serve
```

Screenshot:

[image: The CMD interface]

Comment: No result on php -v?

Comment: @brianforan no, just a blank line. I just noticed that when I type any of those php or composer commands it seems like the CMD crashes for a short period of time. The text in the title ("command prompt") turns gray for a few seconds.

Comment: Maybe you install Composer with wrong location. Should you recheck your Composer path. Maybe you can try to reinstall xampp with default location, then re install Composer with default settings. It's will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reinstall composer from this [link](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
and try it

Comment: During the installation, it says "The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly: D:\xampp\php\php.exe". I'll try to reinstall Xampp and see if that works.

Comment: @user3004798 Ok

Comment: @user3004798 Please check and let me know if any error occur

Comment: By the way, I just downloaded php on http://php.net/downloads.php and used that as the php.exe file.